# How to pull code from the repo I forked?

Tags: git, github

Say there is a project: A.

I made a fork: B.

I made changes to the fork (B) and made a pull request.

By that time main project (A) changed.

I need to pull A (main project) to my PC, merge it with B (fork).

Question is -

How do I pull the main project (A) into my PC?

I do understand that somehow it has to be a new branch (say main/master) that points to A.

But not very clear how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to add the original repository as a new remote repository.  Then you can fetch from this remote and merge your new local copy onto your changes.

```
$ git remote add <name> <source>
$ git fetch <name>
$ git merge <name>/<branch>

# name   = remote's nickname (i.e. upstream)
# source = remote's path (i.e. https://github.com/path/repo.git)
# branch = remote's branch name (i.e. master)
```